# Ionic : Can't display facebook embedded posts in a iFrame on Android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, iframe, ionic-framework

I have some issue with ionic and facebook for displaying a post with the facebook iFrame. It bothers me a little because this method was working 2 months ago and now it seems that it has changed.

I have followed the method provided by [Facebook Developers at this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts?locale=en_US).

The post display very well on a browser but not on a real device. However, I don't have any console error while making request on the phone. Just an iFrame saying the post doesn't exist (It is the one of the example given by Facebook).

I have already install the cordova whitelist plugin for the allow-origins problem.

I really don't see what has changed since the last time. Did facebook made a change in their plugins ? Or am I forgetting something on the device side ?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem - it used to work but now it shows a message like "This facebook post is no longer available". What I have been able to figure out is that it seems to be because the location of the main document in Cordova apps is using the "file:" scheme - not a "real" domain name. Maybe Facebook is actively blocking embedding in hybrid apps or it may be an oversight on Facebooks side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm glad not to be the only one with this problem. I think that Facebook is blocking it too. I'm still currently searching for a solution.

Comment: Any update on the situation? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think as it says in the [facebook developers faqs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs)

for the web simple copy paste works but for ios/android you have to register for a developer's account and register an app as well

this guide might also be of help
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook